# How to make javascript canvas draw faster?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have the following code to display an ECG. I use the canvas to draw the graph background (each grid of 2.5 mm dimension). Later I'm taking the y coordinates from an array **array_1** (x coordinates are calculated within the program). The problem with this approach is it will take around 40 seconds to plot the entire graph since there are 1250 values within array **array_1**. What I could do is I could do the plotting part within a loop in which case, the entire graph is plotted as soon as the page is loaded. But, I need the plotting to happen over the course of 5 seconds. Not more. Not less. How would I alter the code to do this? Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1350" height="1300" style="background-color: white;"></canvas>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctxt = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var n1 = 1;
    var n1_x=49; //Graph x coordinate starting pixel.
    var n1_y=72;//Graph y coordinate starting pixel.
    var array_1 = []// array from which y coordinates are taken. Has 1250 elements
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x=0;
    var y=0;
    var Line_position=-1;
    while(x<=1350)//graph width
    {
        ctxt.lineWidth = "0.5";
        Line_position=Line_position+1;
        if(Line_position%5==0)
        {
            ctxt.lineWidth = "1.5";
        }

        ctxt.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctxt.beginPath();
        ctxt.moveTo(x, 0);
        ctxt.lineTo(x, 1300);
        ctxt.stroke();
        x=x+9.43;

    }

    Line_position=-1;
    while(y<=1300)//graph height
    {
        ctxt.lineWidth = "0.5";
        Line_position=Line_position+1;
        if(Line_position%5==0)
        {
            ctxt.lineWidth = "1.5";
        }

        ctxt.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctxt.beginPath();
        ctxt.moveTo(0, y);
        ctxt.lineTo(1350,y);
        ctxt.stroke();
        y=y+9.43;
    }
   drawWave();
        function drawWave()
        {
          requestAnimationFrame(drawWave);
                ctx.lineWidth = "1";
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
               ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(n1_x- 1, n1_y+array_1[n1-1]);//move to the pixel position
                ctx.lineTo(n1_x, n1_y+array_1[n1]);//Draw to the pixel position
                ctx.stroke();
                n1_x=n1_x+0.374;//Incrementing pixel so as to traverse x axis.
                n1++;
 }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the array:
array_1 = [69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,74,74,74,74,74,74,74,73,73,73,73,74,74,74,74,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,74,74,74,73,73,73,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,71,72,72,72,73,73,73,72,72,72,73,73,73,74,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,72,72,72,71,101,71,70,70,70,69,68,68,67,67,66,66,67,67,69,70,72,72,72,73,73,74,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,74,76,77,76,70,57,40,22,11,11,22,40,57,69,73,73,71,71,71,72,72,73,73,74,74,74,73,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,71,71,70,70,71,71,71,71,70,70,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,68,68,68,67,67,66,66,65,65,64,63,63,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,63,63,64,65,66,67,68,68,69,70,71,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,74,74,74,74,74,74,73,73,72,73,73,73,74,73,73,72,72,72,73,73,73,72,72,73,73,74,74,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,71,70,70,70,70,70,69,69,68,67,67,67,67,68,69,71,72,72,73,73,73,73,74,74,74,74,74,73,73,73,73,75,77,78,76,67,53,35,18,8,10,23,41,58,69,73,72,71,70,71,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,73,73,73,73,72,71,71,70,70,71,71,71,71,71,71,71,71,70,70,69,69,69,69,68,68,67,67,67,67,67,66,65,65,65,64,63,62,61,61,61,60,60,60,59,60,60,60,61,62,63,65,66,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,71,71,72,72,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,71,71,70,70,69,69,69,68,67,67,66,65,66,66,68,69,70,71,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,74,74,74,74,74,74,76,78,78,74,64,48,29,13,5,10,26,45,62,71,73,72,71,71,72,73,73,73,73,73,74,74,74,73,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,71,71,71,71,71,71,71,71,71,70,70,69,69,69,69,68,67,66,66,66,66,65,65,64,63,62,62,61,61,60,60,60,60,61,62,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,70,71,72,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,74,74,75,75,74,74,74,73,73,73,74,73,73,73,73,73,74,74,74,74,74,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,73,73,74,74,74,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,73,73,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,73,73,72,72,71,70,70,70,69,69,68,68,67,67,66,67,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,73,74,74,73,73,73,74,75,75,74,73,73,74,76,78,75,67,52,32,15,5,8,22,41,59,69,73,72,71,70,71,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,71,71,71,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,69,69,69,69,68,68,68,68,67,67,66,65,65,64,64,64,63,62,61,60,60,60,60,60,61,61,62,62,63,64,65,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,71,71,71,71,71,72,72,73,73,73,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,71,71,71,71,71,71,71,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,71,71,71,72,72,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,73,73,74,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,71,71,71,70,70,70,70,69,69,68,67,67,68,69,71,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,74,75,75,75,74,74,74,75,77,77,75,67,52,34,18,10,12,26,45,62,71,74,73,72,72,72,73,74,74,74,75,75,74,74,74,74,74,74,74,74,74,73,73,73,73,74,74,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,71,71,71,71,71,70,70,70,69,69,69,68,68,68,68,67,66,65,64,63,63,62,62,62,63,63,63,63,64,65,66,67,69,69,70,71,72,72,73,73,74,74,74,74,75,75,76,76,74,72,70,70,69,69 ];

Comment: Could you clarify the following: `I need the plotting to happen within 5 seconds. Not more. Not less.`This does not make sense semantically. "Within" implies that any time up to and including the target is acceptable. Do you mean that `rendering should take no more than 5 seconds`? Also, you should include a sample data-set.

Comment: @enhzflep: Sorry about that. What I was meaning was that, the plotting of the entire 1250 points of the graph should happen within 5 seconds. In my system, it takes 40 seconds to take all the 1250 y coordinates from the array_1 and plot the graph. My employer has asked me to make it in such a manner that the ECG will finish rendering in exactly 5 seconds. How do I make the rendering faster so that it will take precisely 5 seconds to finish plotting the graph once the page has been loaded?

Comment: no problem, I've edited your question to reflect what I understand you to want. Just to be extra clear - am I correct in thinking that you wish to animate the drawing? That is to say, do you wish for the entire data-set to be drawn in the space of 5 seconds? If so, consider the number of frames per second you wish for animation, then multiply this by the target time. Assuming 5 seconds and 30fps, you have 150 frames to cover the whole data-set. Simply divide the size of the data-set by this number and you have the number of points you need to plot per frame. 1250/150 = 8.333

Comment: No problem, we all start somewhere. Same. I'd be happy to have more of a look if you could supply a sample data-set. An off-site link would be fine, but you could just edit your question to include it. As it stands, all I know about the data is the number of points. I've no idea of the range and to be perfectly frank, am disinclined to try to create a reasonable one in order to try to solve the problem. I'm happy to attempt the problem with said data. (I don't consider you to be pestering. ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably go about the task something like this. As mentioned in a comment, we need to draw a number of the data-points per-frame. How many we draw depends on the speed that the browser is able to supply an animation frame.

I've hard-coded the value to 4, since that seems to work on my machine, but with not much more work you can probably make the code time itself and adjust this value on the fly so that your animation runs for as close as possible to the target time. I had a quick go, but the results were awful, I'll leave that as an exercise in research or thought for the reader.

By keeping track of how many frames we've already drawn for the current 'refresh-cycle', we know how far to index into the array for the first point to be drawn for each frame.

I've tried to parameterize the code as much as possible, but it's late and I'm tired, I may have overlooked something somewhere.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(id,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementById(id);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);
function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    drawBkg(byId('canvas'), 9.43, 5, "0.5", "1.5", "black");
    drawCurFrame();
}

var dataSamples = [69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,74,74,74,74,74,74,74,73,73,73,73,74,74,74,74,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,74,74,74,73,73,73,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,71,72,72,72,73,73,73,72,72,72,73,73,73,74,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,72,72,72,71,101,71,70,70,70,69,68,68,67,67,66,66,67,67,69,70,72,72,72,73,73,74,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,74,76,77,76,70,57,40,22,11,11,22,40,57,69,73,73,71,71,71,72,72,73,73,74,74,74,73,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,71,71,70,70,71,71,71,71,70,70,69,69,69,69,69,69,69,68,68,68,67,67,66,66,65,65,64,63,63,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,62,63,63,64,65,66,67,68,68,69,70,71,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,74,74,74,74,74,74,73,73,72,73,73,73,74,73,73,72,72,72,73,73,73,72,72,73,73,74,74,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,71,70,70,70,70,70,69,69,68,67,67,67,67,68,69,71,72,72,73,73,73,73,74,74,74,74,74,73,73,73,73,75,77,78,76,67,53,35,18,8,10,23,41,58,69,73,72,71,70,71,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,73,73,73,73,72,71,71,70,70,71,71,71,71,71,71,71,71,70,70,69,69,69,69,68,68,67,67,67,67,67,66,65,65,65,64,63,62,61,61,61,60,60,60,59,60,60,60,61,62,63,65,66,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,71,71,72,72,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,71,71,70,70,69,69,69,68,67,67,66,65,66,66,68,69,70,71,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,74,74,74,74,74,74,76,78,78,74,64,48,29,13,5,10,26,45,62,71,73,72,71,71,72,73,73,73,73,73,74,74,74,73,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,71,71,71,71,71,71,71,71,71,70,70,69,69,69,69,68,67,66,66,66,66,65,65,64,63,62,62,61,61,60,60,60,60,61,62,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,70,71,72,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,74,74,75,75,74,74,74,73,73,73,74,73,73,73,73,73,74,74,74,74,74,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,73,73,74,74,74,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,73,73,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,73,73,72,72,71,70,70,70,69,69,68,68,67,67,66,67,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,73,74,74,73,73,73,74,75,75,74,73,73,74,76,78,75,67,52,32,15,5,8,22,41,59,69,73,72,71,70,71,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,71,71,71,70,70,70,70,70,70,70,69,69,69,69,68,68,68,68,67,67,66,65,65,64,64,64,63,62,61,60,60,60,60,60,61,61,62,62,63,64,65,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,71,71,71,71,71,72,72,73,73,73,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,71,71,71,71,71,71,71,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,71,71,71,72,72,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,73,73,74,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,72,72,71,71,71,70,70,70,70,69,69,68,67,67,68,69,71,72,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,74,75,75,75,74,74,74,75,77,77,75,67,52,34,18,10,12,26,45,62,71,74,73,72,72,72,73,74,74,74,75,75,74,74,74,74,74,74,74,74,74,73,73,73,73,74,74,73,73,73,73,73,73,73,72,72,71,71,71,71,71,70,70,70,69,69,69,68,68,68,68,67,66,65,64,63,63,62,62,62,63,63,63,63,64,65,66,67,69,69,70,71,72,72,73,73,74,74,74,74,75,75,76,76,74,72,70,70,69,69 ];

function drawBkg(canvasElem, squareSize, numSquaresPerBlock, minorLineWidthStr, majorLineWidthStr, lineColStr)
{
    var nLinesDone = 0;
    var i, curX, curY;
    var ctx = canvasElem.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasElem.width,canvasElem.height);

    // draw the vertical lines
    curX=0;
    ctx.strokeStyle = lineColStr;
    while (curX < canvasElem.width)
    {
        if (nLinesDone % numSquaresPerBlock == 0)
            ctx.lineWidth = majorLineWidthStr;
        else
            ctx.lineWidth = minorLineWidthStr;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(curX, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(curX, canvasElem.height);
        ctx.stroke();

        curX += squareSize;
        nLinesDone++;
    }

    // draw the horizontal lines
    curY=0;
    nLinesDone = 0;
    while (curY < canvasElem.height)
    {
        if (nLinesDone % numSquaresPerBlock == 0)
            ctx.lineWidth = majorLineWidthStr;
        else
            ctx.lineWidth = minorLineWidthStr;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, curY);
        ctx.lineTo(canvasElem.width, curY);
        ctx.stroke();

        curY += squareSize;
        nLinesDone++;
    }
}

// position that will be treated as 0,0 when drawing our points.
var originX=49;
var originY=72;

function drawSamples(nSamplesToDraw, firstSample, lineWidthStr, lineColourStr)
{
    var can = byId('canvas');
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

    ctx.strokeStyle = lineColourStr;
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidthStr;
    console.log(firstSample);
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.moveTo( originX+firstSample-1, dataSamples[firstSample-1]+originY );
    for (var i=0; i<nSamplesToDraw; i++)
    {
        var curSample = dataSamples[i + firstSample];
        ctx.lineTo( originX+firstSample+i, curSample+originY );
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}

var curFrame=0;
var nPointsPerFrame = 4;
function drawCurFrame()
{
    if ((dataSamples.length - (nPointsPerFrame * curFrame)) < nPointsPerFrame)      // will we over-run the end of the array of datapoints?
    {
        curFrame = 0;                                                               // if so, reset
        drawBkg(byId('canvas'), 9.43, 5, "0.5", "1.5", "black");
    }
    drawSamples(nPointsPerFrame, nPointsPerFrame*curFrame, "1", "blue");
    curFrame++;
    requestAnimationFrame( drawCurFrame );
}
</script>

<style>
#canvas
{
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id='txt'></div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1350" height="1300"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Now that I see you have provided some more info I get what you want.

The problem is you need to draw a fixed number of line segments within time `t`.

As you do not know how long each frame could take you can not rely on a fixed frame rate. The alternative it to just use the current time and save the end time.

Get the start time and then each frame draw all the should be drawn until the current time. As the line segments being drawn will not be displayed until the next screen refresh the time you get will be approx 16ms behind so will need to adjust for that.

What I have done is keep track of the average frame time and used half that time to estimate when the new canvas update will be displayed.

Its a bit pedantic but might as well show how to get a required time as close as possible. If you dont care its a few ms out then just remove the average frame time stuff. You will be at most 30ms off on a slow machine.

```
var canvas; // canvas
var ctx; 

function getCanvas () {
    // to do 
    // get canvas and context
}
function drawGrid () {
    // to do
    // draw the grid
}
function drawTimedLine(){
    if(canvas === undefined){ // if the canvas not available get it
       getCanvas();
    }
    // clear the canvas is repeating animation
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawGrid();

    var array_1 = ; // your data


    // All stuff needed for timed animation.
    // The frame you render will not be displayed untill the next
    // vertical refresh which is unknown, Assume it is one frame.
    var startDelay = 1000;      // if Needed time in milliseconds to delay start
    var endTime;                // hold the time that the animation has to end
    var lastDataPoint;          // holds the last point drawn to
    var timeToDraw = 5 * 1000;  // how long the animation should last
    var repeatAfter = 1 *1000;  // if you want to repeat the animatoin
    var frameCount = 0;         // count the frames to get average frame time
    var startTime;              //the start time;
    var numberPoints = array_1.length; // number of points;
    var startX = 49;            // line starts at
    var yOffset = 72;           // line Y offset
    var endX = 512;             // line ends at. 
    var width = endX - startX;  // width  
    var xStep = width / numberPoints;   // X step per point
    var pointsPerMS = numberPoints / timeToDraw; // get how many points per ms should be drawn

    // function to draw
    function drawWave() {
        // variable needed
        var averageframeTime, timeLeft, i, currentTime;
        currentTime = new Date().valueOf();     // gets the time in millisecond;
        if (startTime === undefined) {          // Is this the first frame      
            startTime = currentTime;            // save the start time;
            endTime = currentTime + timeToDraw; // workout when the end time is;
            lastDataPoint = 0;                  // set the data position to the start;
            averageframeTime = 0;               // no frames counted so frame time is zero          
        } else {
            frameCount += 1;                    // count the frames
            // get the average frame time
            averageframeTime = (currentTime - startTime) / frameCount; 
        }
        // get the time this frame
        // will most likely be displayed
        // then calculate how long
        // till the end
        timeLeft = endTime - Math.min(endTime, currentTime + averageframeTime / 2); 

        // now get where we should
        // be when the frame is presented
        pointPos = Math.floor(pointsPerMS * (timeToDraw - timeLeft)); 


        // now draw the points from where we last left of
        // till the new pos;
        ctx.lineWidth = 4;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(  // move to first point
            lastDataPoint * xStep + startX,
            array_1[lastDataPoint] + yOffset 
        ); 
        // draw each line from the last drawn to the new position 
        for (i = lastDataPoint + 1; i <= pointPos && i < numberPoints; i++) { 
            // Add the line segment
            ctx.lineTo(
                i * xStep + startX, 
                array_1[i] + yOffset
            );
        }
        ctx.stroke();                   // execute the render commands
        lastDataPoint = pointPos;       // update the last point
        if (pointPos < numberPoints) {  // are we there yet???
            requestAnimationFrame(drawWave); // no so request another frame
        }else{
            // if you want to repeat the animation
            setTimeout(drawTimedLine , repeatAfter ); 
        } 
    }
    // start the line animation with delay if needed
    setTimeout(drawWave,startDelay);
}    

// use this if you want it to start as soon as page is ready.    
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",drawTimedLine);
// or use if you want it to start when page has images loaded and is ready
// document.addEventListener("load",drawTimedLine);
```

I have also added the ability to repeat the animation. If not needed just remove that code

**My original answer**

Dont know what the problem is with speed as it runs quite well on my machine.

To set up a better start use

```
function startFunction(){
   // your code
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",startFunction);
```

This will wait until the page has loaded and parsed the page. Images and other media may not have loaded but the page is ready to be manipulated.

Not sure what you mean with 5 seconds. Assuming you may want the thing to sart in 5 seconds.

The following will do that.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {setTimeout(startFunction,5000);});
```

I would ask why plot the graph one entry at a time with `requestAnimationFrame` 1250 is not that many lines to draw. If you add `ctx.beginPath()` `ctx.moveTo(/*first point*/)` then loop all points with `ctx.moveTo(/*points*/)` then `ctx.stroke()` will run realtime on but the slowest of devices.

BTW `ctx.lineWidth` is a `Number` not a string. Also you have two context? Use the one context for the canvas. Remove `ctxt` and just use `ctx` and finally you don't need to add  `type='text/javascript'` to the script tag as Javascript is the default.

Comment: The `load` event **does** wait until images are loaded, `DOMContentLoaded` does not.

Answer (score 0):

1) It cannot take that long to draw 1000 lines, even 100000 lines won't take more than 10 ms on any decent Browser. Look else where the time is lost.
2) The core issue of your code is that it lacks modularity. Split your code into a few clear functions, group the parameters into a few objects only, name and indent things properly.

Below an (incomplete but working) example of how this might look.

```js
var cv, ctx;
var data = null;
var debug = true;

// ---------------------------------------

// define here all graphic related parameters
var gfxParams = {
  canvasWidth: 600,
  canvasHeight: 600,
  gridColor: '#A66',
  gridSpacing: 10,
  gridLineWidth: 0.5,
  gridStrongLinesEvery: 5,
  lineColor: '#AEB',
  lastLineColor: '#8A9' // , ...
};

// define here all animation related parameters
var animationParams = {
  duration: 5,
  startTime: -1
}


// ---------------------------------------
//              main
// ---------------------------------------

window.onload = function() {
  data = getData();
  setupCanvas(data);
  launchAnimation();
}

// ---------------------------------------

// 
function setupCanvas(data) {
  cv = document.getElementById('cv');
  cv.width = gfxParams.canvasWidth;
  cv.height = gfxParams.canvasHeight;
  ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
  // here you should translate and scale the context
  // so that it shows your data.
}

function drawGrid(ctx) {
  var i = 0,
    pos = 0,
    lw = gfxParams.gridLineWidth;
  ctx.fillStyle = gfxParams.gridColor;
  var vLineCount = gfxParams.canvasWidth / gfxParams.gridSpacing;
  for (i = 0; i < vLineCount; i++) {
    pos = i * gfxParams.gridSpacing;
    ctx.fillRect(pos, 0, lw, gfxParams.canvasHeight);
  }
  var hLineCount = gfxParams.canvasHeight / gfxParams.gridSpacing;
  for (i = 0; i < hLineCount; i++) {
    pos = i * gfxParams.gridSpacing;
    ctx.fillRect(0, pos, gfxParams.canvasWidth, lw);
  }
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  var now = Date.now();
  // erase screen
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, gfxParams.canvasWidth, gfxParams.canvasHeight);
  // draw grid
  drawGrid(ctx);
  // draw lines 
  var lastIndex = getLastDrawnIndex(data, now - animationParams.startTime);
  drawLines(ctx, data, lastIndex);
  if (debug) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillText(lastIndex + ' lines drawn. Time elapsed : ' + (now - animationParams.startTime), 10, 10);
    ctx.restore();
  }
}

// comment
function launchAnimation() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  animationParams.startTime = Date.now();
}

// comment
function getData() {
  var newData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    newData.push([Math.random() * 600, Math.random() * 600]);
  }
  return newData;
}

// comment
function getLastDrawnIndex(data, timeElapsed_ms) {
  var timeElapsed = timeElapsed_ms / 1000;
  if (timeElapsed >= animationParams.duration) return data.length - 1;
  return Math.floor(data.length * timeElapsed / animationParams.duration);
}

function drawLines(ctx, data, lastIndex) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = gfxParams.lineColor;
  // other ctx setup here.
  for (var i = 0; i < lastIndex - 1; i++) {
    drawLine(ctx, data[i], data[i + 1]);
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = gfxParams.lastLineColor;
  drawLine(ctx, data[lastIndex - 1], data[lastIndex]);
}

function drawLine(ctx, p1, p2) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p1[0], p1[1]);
  ctx.lineTo(p2[0], p2[1]);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id='cv'></canvas>
```